# How do I stop further controller processing when using a controller before="OtherController"?

Tags: controllers, routing

I have a controller which is configured to handle requests prior to the core controller using a config.xml similar to this;

```
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <catalogsearch>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <myextension before="Mage_CatalogSearch">My_Extension</myextension>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </catalogsearch>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

The action it overrides should occasionally pass-through to the next (CatalogSearch) controller, and other times should execute it's own action and return--without running the CatalogSearch action.

```
class My_Controller extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if ($this->shouldRun())
        {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();
            // Stop further processing
        }

        // Continue to next controller
    }
}
```

In my controller action how can I prevent the next controller from being called?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
parent::actionName();
```

if im not mistaken.

Comment: In this case I'm not actually inheriting from the controller, just intercepting a request to it.  Although I may just switch to inheritance as it's not a big issue in my current scenario.

Comment: I think that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the main goal of it, but like you described it in the second code listing, there should be just an else path because you state, that you want to stop further processing?

If I am wrong, can you please be a little bit more precise on what you want to achieve.

It would also not hurt to inherit the Mage_CatalogSearch_*Controller you want to rewrite.

Comment: In my code example I would like the response to return at the `// Stop` comment--however using a `return` there still seems to execute the next controller action.  My question is how do I stop the next controller from running when using the `before=""` attribute to intercept a request/route?